# Discord.js help command to compile list of commands and embed with thumbnails

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a very simple Discord bot that posts images/gifs on command by linking Imgur/Tenor htmls.

The commands are stored in individual `.js` files `./commands/`

I would like to create a help command that collects all current commands in the folder, and embeds the command name, with the executed command beneath it so that a thumbnail of the image/gif is created, but I mostly just about managed to follow the Discord.js guide so I'm very very new to this. Can anyone suggest some code to help me get started? How can I populate embed fields based on an array of existing commands?

Example of bot below:

The commands are imported in `index.js` via:

```js
    client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
            const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
            client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    }
```

And executed via:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
        const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    
        if (!client.commands.has(commandName)) return;
        const command = client.commands.get(commandName); 
    
        try {
                    command.execute(message, args);
            } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                    message.reply('Something bad happened!');
            }
    });
```

An example of a command `./commands/test.js` is:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'test',
    description: 'A test',
    execute(message, args) {
        message.channel.send('This is a test.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `.forEach()` loop.
For example:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    description: 'View a full list of commands',
    execute(message, client) {
        const Discord = require('discord.js');
        const embed = Discord.MessageEmbed();

        client.commands.forEach(command => {
            embed.addField(`${command.name}`, `${command.description}`, false);
        }
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is really useful. Will this also execute each command so that the image is added as a field? In the example of `test.js` command, I usually use a URL in the `message.channel.send('This is a test.');` command. I'm trying to figure out how to make each command execute.